# celery worker does not start correctly within supervisord

Tags: python-3.x, celery, supervisord

I have setup the supervisor according celery supervisor configuration example given in the celery document page. However, looks like the workers do not start correctly. Here is the configuration:

```
[program:celery-1]
command=celery worker -A tasks.user -l DEBUG -n userworker1 -Q user_works
directory=/home/myuser/projects/myproc
user=root
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/userworker1.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/userworker1.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998
```

I checked the userworker1.log and found no tasks were displayed during starting.

However, if I run it in command terminal. like the following:

```
celery worker -A tasks.user -l INFO -n userworker1 -Q user_works
```

I see

```
 -------------- celery@userworker1 v3.1.11 (Cipater)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.5.0-23-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-12.04-precise
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x394ea50
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- 
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> user_works       exchange=user_works(direct) key=user_works


[tasks]
  . user.finduser
  . user.refreshuser
  . user.updateuser
```

Any idea on what is wrong with the celeryd.conf?

Comment: again. looks like it is not an issue. I just typoed the queue name.